# Appending an object to a object of properties and array of object using angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an object which contains 2 properties and array of 4 objects($scope.details)
I am trying to append  a new object as a property to $scope.details.

[image]

this is the way i am trying:

```
         var routeId;
         var obj=new Object();
         obj.routeId = $routeParams.id;
         $scope.details = obj;
```

however not getting results.
any suggestion on this?

Comment: Can you please replace the image with complete code? It is much easier for people to try and reconstruct your issue copying and pasting code, rather than reading it from an image. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve]. If possible, create live demo that'll show the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood, you want to append `$routeParams.id` to `$scope.details`.
So `$scope.details = yourNewObject` **will NOT** work, as it will just replace it and not append it.

why `var obj=new Object()` when you can just `var obj={}`?

**Solution:**

```
$scope.details['routeId']=$routeParams.id
```

OR

```
$scope.details.routeId=$routeParams.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
     var routeId = "some value";
     var obj=new Object();
     obj["routeId"]= $routeParams.id;
     $scope.details = obj;
```

Or you could simply do this..

```
var obj = {};
ob.propertyName = $routeParams.id;
$scope.details = obj;
```

We would like to see some code, before we could give more app solutions.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say what is happening here without some more code.

However, it's likely that you are updating your `$scope` object outside of an angular "digest cycle", so angular is not aware of the change. 
http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-angulars-apply-digest/

To force angular to run a digest cycle, you can call `$scope.$apply()`

```
var obj = {
    routeId: $routeParams.id
};
$scope.details = obj;
$scope.$apply();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking about this way too hard, nothing to do with Angular.

If you want $scope.details to contain something called route just add it.

```
$scope.details.route = {"routeId": $routeParams.id, "YourOtherAwesomeRouteStuff": "OtherCoolValues"}
```